# Alternative to calling stored procedure in a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a query looking at some transaction information.  The time period criteria is conditional - on the 5th of the month, it needs to look at days 16-last day of the previous month.  On the 20th of the month, it needs to look at days 1-15 of the same month.  It will run automatically.  A fine gentleman or woman on Stack Overflow gave me the following stored procedure to use, which worked perfectly:

```
DECLARE @today SMALLDATETIME, @start SMALLDATETIME, @end SMALLDATETIME; 
SET @today = DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));

SET @start = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(@today), @today); 
SET @end = DATEADD(DAY, 15, @start);  

IF DATEPART(DAY, @today) <= 15 
BEGIN     
    SET @start = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @end);     
    SET @end = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(@today), @today); 
END   

SELECT ... WHERE h.billed_date >= @start AND h.billed_date < @end;
```

Now they want this converted to a view that they can access from a 3rd party data integration tool.  Google tells me views can't call stored procedures in SQL Server.  Their DBA said the whole query could also be converted to a stored procedure.  How do I convert a query into an SP so that it can be accessed by a data integration tool?  Here's a simplified version of the query.

```
SELECT
  c.customer_name
, cc.category_name
, h.acct_bal  

FROM 
customer c
inner join htransactions h on c.customer_id = h.customer_id
left outer join customer_category cc on cc.category_id = c.category_id

WHERE
h.billed date >= @start
AND h.billed date < @end
```

Thanks.  I'm a business analyst trying to get better at SQL. My foundational querying SQL is getting stronger.  I need to transistion to learning more about variables and stored procedures.

Comment: And the 3rd party data integration tool can't call a stored procedure? I wouldn't call that much of a data integration tool.

Comment: Is this a stored procedure instead of a view just because you are assigning the `@start` and `@end` variables with an `IF`?, or there is another reason?

Comment: No, it can definitely call a stored procedure.

Comment: I guess I should have just asked how to convert a query into a stored procedure.

Comment: I think you can easily convert that procedure to table-valued UDF that behaves pretty much the same as view and can appear in `FROM`.

Comment: You need to learn about user defined functions. You can get the functinoality you want using create function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this just needs to be a stored procedure, then:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PullData -- whatever
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @today SMALLDATETIME, @start SMALLDATETIME, @end SMALLDATETIME; 

    SET @today = DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));

    SET @start = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(@today), @today); 
    SET @end = DATEADD(DAY, 15, @start);  

    IF DATEPART(DAY, @today) <= 15 
    BEGIN     
        SET @start = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @end);     
        SET @end = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(@today), @today); 
    END   

    SELECT ... WHERE h.billed_date >= @start AND h.billed_date < @end; 
END
GO
```